# How can we embed an exe containing a payload into a pdf file

Tags: metasploit, pdf, code-execution

I have created an exe with a payload which gives me a meterpreter session. But I need to embed this exe into a pdf. Upon opening the pdf the exe ideally should get executed. Is there any way to do this embedding and auto run of exe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Embedding is very easy, it's a bit harder to open it. Here's the Javascript to run it:

```
this.exportDataObject({
    cName: "myExploit.exe",
    nLaunch: 2,
});
```

Adobe Reader and others won't let you just run any file although, like .exe/.vbs etc., so you need to find a way to bypass it. There are methods described in the reference article below, if you would like to go a bit deeper into that.

Reference article:
https://nora.codes/post/pdf-embedding-attacks/